# Why the following data produce wrong chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, raphael, graphael

I am using linegraph of graphael.

I have this line to produce my graph

```
    var lines = r.linechart(30, 30, 600, 440,[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71]],[[0.03091,0.00461,0.0068,0.00144,0.00544,0.00035,0.00871,0.03117,0.02259,0.02623,0.01967,0.01967,0.00788,0.02217,0.0137,0.01237,0.01764,0.0131,0.00942,0.0076,0.01463,0.02882,0.02093,0.02502,0.01961,0.01551,0.02227,0.0164,0.0191,0.00774,0.03076,0.0281,0.01338,0.02763,0.02334,0.00557,0.00023,0.01523,0.0263,0.03077,0.02404,0.02492,0.01954,5E-05,0.02337,0.01715,0.02271,0.00815,0.01343,0.00985,0.01837,0.00749,0.02967,0.01156,0.0083,0.00209,0.01538,0.01348,0.01353,0.02163,0.00977,0.02401,0.01207,0.01485,0.02717,0.02327,0.00629,0.01195,0.03052,0.00812,0.01215,0.00241]], {nostroke: false, axis: "0 0 1 1", symbol: "circle", smooth: true })
```

However, the above data, make the graphael graph, to have wrong labels at the y axis when the graph is produced. Can you help me with that? I am stuck since yesterday at this thing...

***At least can anyone run it, just to tell me if he can run it normally?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry ! You are not the first one to [encounter this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097540/weird-chart-maximum-axis-x-value-real-challenge).

I would recommend to multiply your value by 10 or 100, which should solve the problem and could be easily presented in the chart legend.

For example:

```
data = [0.03091,0.00461,0.0068,0.00144,0.00544,0.00035,0.00871,0.03117,0.02259,0.02623,0.01967,0.01967,0.00788,0.02217,0.0137,0.01237,0.01764,0.0131,0.00942,0.0076,0.01463,0.02882,0.02093,0.02502,0.01961,0.01551,0.02227,0.0164,0.0191,0.00774,0.03076,0.0281,0.01338,0.02763,0.02334,0.00557,0.00023,0.01523,0.0263,0.03077,0.02404,0.02492,0.01954,5E-05,0.02337,0.01715,0.02271,0.00815,0.01343,0.00985,0.01837,0.00749,0.02967,0.01156,0.0083,0.00209,0.01538,0.01348,0.01353,0.02163,0.00977,0.02401,0.01207,0.01485,0.02717,0.02327,0.00629,0.01195,0.03052,0.00812,0.01215,0.00241];

data = data.map(function(x) { return x * 1000; });

r.linechart(30, 30, 600, 440,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71],data, {nostroke: false, axis: "0 0 1 1", symbol: "circle", smooth: true })
```

It seems to work as workaround.

Comment: Thanks a lot frouil. To be honest, this does not solve my problem, as when the user hovers at a point the real value will appear, as well as at the axis... Can you come up with something, that can help me a little bit more with that? Like for example a way, that I can use your suggestion, but when the user hovers at a point to show the 1/1000 of its value...

Comment: Thanks a lot friend! I combined what you said, with my comment above, and made it succeed! thanks a lot! :)