# Weird chart maximum axis x value (Real Challenge)

Tags: javascript, charts, raphael, graphael

Here you can see a chart created using graphael. http://jsfiddle.net/aNJxf/4/

It is shown with it's y axis correctly.

The first y value is 0.03100 and the maximum value at y axis is at 0.031
If we change the value to 0.03104 the maximum value at y axis becomes 1.03 and now all our points are in the bottom.
If we add another 0.00001, which makes that value 0.03105, the maximum at the axis y becomes 0.531 and now our points are shown at the ***wrong*** position of the chart.
It seems that something is going wrong while graphael calculates the maximum y axis value.

Why this happens? And how we can fix that?

The code that I have pasted there is

```
var r = Raphael("holder"),
txtattr = { font: "12px sans-serif" };

var x = [], y = [], y2 = [], y3 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    x[i] = i * 10;
    y[i] = (y[i - 1] || 0) + (Math.random() * 7) - 3;
}
var demoX = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],[3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7, 8]];
var demoY = [[12, 32, 23, 15, 17, 27, 22], [10, 20, 30, 25, 15, 28]];

var xVals =[7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58];
var yVals = [0.03100,0.02259,0.02623,0.01967,0.01967,0.00788,0.02217,0.0137,0.01237,0.01764,0.0131,0.00942,0.0076,0.01463,0.02882,0.02093,0.02502,0.01961,0.01551,0.02227,0.0164,0.0191,0.00774,0.03076,0.0281,0.01338,0.02763,0.02334,0.00557,0.00023,0.01523,0.0263,0.03077,0.02404,0.02492,0.01954,0.01954,0.02337,0.01715,0.02271,0.00815,0.01343,0.00985,0.01837,0.00749,0.02967,0.01156,0.0083,0.00209,0.01538,0.01348,0.01353];

//r.text(160, 10, "Symbols, axis and hover effect").attr(txtattr);
var lines = r.linechart(10, 10, 300, 220, xVals, yVals, { nostroke: false, axis: "0 0 1 1", symbol: "circle", smooth: true })
    .hoverColumn(function () {
        this.tags = r.set();

        for (var i = 0, ii = this.y.length; i < ii; i++) {
            this.tags.push(r.tag(this.x, this.y[i], this.values[i], 160, 10).insertBefore(this).attr([{ fill: "#fff" }, { fill: this.symbols[i].attr("fill") }]));
            }
        }, function () {
            this.tags && this.tags.remove();
            });

lines.symbols.attr({ r: 3 });
```

Thanks

Comment: A similar question was asked and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095968/why-the-following-data-produce-wrong-chart/21117316#21117316)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not real familiar with gRaphael, but I did find that converting your `yVals` into whole numbers (by multiplying each by `1e5`) seemed to rid your chart of the awkward behavior.

This suggests that it could be related to the algorithm gRaphael uses to find the max axis value (as you ask in [your related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21098797/1225950)) when your values are small decimal values (and alter at even more significant digits).

I know there are inherent issues with float precision, but I can't be sure that applies to your case, or that your values are low enough to consider this.

Not the best workaround, but if it would be feasible for you, you could display the `yValues` in an order of magnitude larger, and remind the viewer that they are actually smaller than presented.  For example, your chart could go from 0 to 3100 and remind your viewer that the scale is `scale * 1e-5`.